# C++ class design

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns

Maybe this is not pure c++ technical question, but any advice is highly welcome.

I need to implement class with many members (let's say A).

I also need to access these data by set of other classes and this access should be quite fast (drawing stuff conditioned by members from class A).

First approach was to set access level inside A as private and use kind of setters/getters to get particular elements to check (so many method calls).

Other approach, just make everything public in A, next one to make dozen of friend classes. To be honest, i do not like any of the above. Rest of system shouldn't have access to A class members at all, only interested ones.

Maybe someone had to deal with something similar and could advice some good practice, maybe some appropriate design pattern?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Perhaps the base problem is "many members". :-)  Could you not separate the problem into a few smaller sub-problems? Then perhaps some of the unease will go away? Otherwise, inlined getters would not give you a performance difference to public variables. So don't worry about that.  And the "drawing stuff" will like be where you spend most time anyway. On the other hand, "dozens of friends" seems like something to avoid.

Comment: @Raindrop7 I've tested all mentioned in the post. In fact all of them are working fine, but are "not quite elegant" in my opinion. So, maybe there is something better than that.

Comment: @BoPersson Yeah, that's another approach, 'im trying to get right now. However this is kind of electric system with many small elements (switches, contractors etc.)

Comment: What was the downside of private data with getters and setters?

Comment: Encapsulation in general aids in understanding and future flexibility (see this [GOTW](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/070.htm)). So unless your class is there simply to aggregate pieces of data together without any behavior, you almost certainly want to avoid public data members and a multitude of friends. Another option beyond what you have listed is to use the observer pattern to notify interested parties of changes -- converting a pull (or poll) to a push.

Comment: @KennyOstrom Nothing really bad i think, at least it is best comparing to the others. I was just a little worried about performance due to many method calls, but as Bo said - probably there is no big difference between setter/getter and public access.

Comment: It sounds like you are not trying to encapsulate your data so I would think a basic `struct`  with all public members would be appropriate. But it also sounds like you might benefit from breaking this down into smaller components.

Comment: I suspect that your "I do not like" feeling comes from lacking a higher-level idea what the object is and does. It doesn't seem like a class because it feels more like a struct with an encapsulation facade. Slapping on a getter and setter doesn't really mean much in the grand scheme if you only do it to be more object oriented, but if you later use them to completely replace the internals with ... a database or whatever ... then you will probably like it. But if it is a glorified struct, the getters/setters are just more typing for you (even if the compiler optimizes them away).

Answer (score 0):

If your class is more than a dumb collection of data and flags, the proper approach would be to add whatever you are *doing* with the data *into* the class, instead of exposing it with get/set.

For example, if you are pulling coordinates, colors, and line thickness from a class 'Polygon' to draw it, you should instead add a method into the class that does the drawing (and pass the drawing context in as a parameter).

Comment: The issue here is that this class is no just set of data/flags, but also would do something more (be in fact kind of system). So that's why i wanted encapsulation. Also there not only one class will draw components of this system. But as colleagues suggested above, some better design regarding smaller parts should do the trick regarding better feeling about this stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Of the two options I would prefer the getter/setter way, because public members are not a good idea especially if most parts of your system mustn't access these members.
So (even if your question is enough general and greedy of details) if you are worried by "uncontrolled access" maybe a solution could be

- declare members **private**( at most protected, if base class has some subclass that can access to them)
- use **getters/setters** for the members that can be reached by everyone
- use **friend** class(or **friend methods** to access to private/protected members that shouln't be accessed by random classes).

Finally, you should try to reduce the amount of different classes accessing to your members, as far as possible,defining a common virtual class in order to provide a common set of valid methods for every subclass.